# how hibernate deal with like keyword in query sentence

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Here met a hesitation about the way hibernate dealing with **like** keyword in query sentence.This's a small snippet in DaoImpl and see it first:

```
public List<T> findBySQL(String sql, String... params){
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity(clazz);
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
        query.setParameter(i, params[i]);
    }
    List<T> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

ok! without any doubt and use it in below controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFirst/{var}", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody Site getFirst(@PathVariable String var){

    String fr = "select * from Food f where f.resname = ?";
    List<Site> siteList = siteService.findBySQL(fr, var);
    Site first = siteList.get(0);
    return first;
}
```

here is the result:`{"src":"http://p0.meituan.net/350.214/deal/ac8ba922d7a6030325976fb31e51b4ce38985.jpg","resname":"哈哈派"}`

but when i change such sql sentence like this using **like** and without amending anything else:

`String fr = "select * from Food f where f.resname like '%?%'";
 List<Site> siteList = siteService.findBySQL(fr, var);`

redeploy and run, exception appear:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
```

but i don't think it's the parameter index problem, maybe something error or maybe like can not be used like such way? so i wonder how hibernate deal with 'like' keyword?

Comment: The raw string `'%?%'` is not recognized to contain a parameter, and that is it's correct behaviour. You can place a parameter instead of a value binding, but not inside one.

Comment: Just, don't create your SQLs in a controller :)

Comment: @veljkost but i need the variable in getFirst method, if i don't create sql in controller, where should i create it?

Comment: You can, for starters, move it to your service method and remove a parameter from a method definition, or create a new service method with appropriate name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the wildchar(%) to the **parameter** and not the query. So modify your query as below.

```
String fr = "select * from Food f where f.resname like ? ";
List<Site> siteList = siteService.findBySQL(fr, "%"+var+"%");

 OR

String fr = "select * from Food f where f.resname like ? ";
List<Site> siteList = siteService.findBySQL(fr, new String[]{"%"+var+"%"});
```

Comment: actually both are the same, you can see i use string... in DaoImpl, and you answer give me inspiration about the right usage of like in hibernate.